# DB::get is Array in Laravel but it says it is not array

Tags: laravel

I thought the data which is from DB::get() is Array.
However , the console says it is not array.

```
                $fruitList =  Food::where('id' => 300)->get(['id']);             
                shuffle($fruitList);
```

> ErrorException: shuffle() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in file

Comment: Did you try checking [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#retrieving-all-rows-from-a-table)? "*The get method returns an Illuminate\Support\Collection instance containing the results of the query where each result is an instance of the PHP stdClass object.*"

Comment: im sure its a typo but `where('id' => 300)` is a wrong syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `get()` is not an array. it's [Laravel array collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections) you can convert it to an array or use shuffle of array collection:

```
$fruitList =  Food::where('id' => 300)->get(['id'])->toArray();             
shuffle($fruitList);
```

with array collection:

```
$fruitList =  Food::where('id' => 300)->get(['id'])->shuffle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like @A.seddighi mentioned, using `get() or all()` gives you a collection. It may seem like an array when you output it using return or print but it is different.

Collections can be filtered, queried and so on. e.g

```
$fruitList->has('price')
```

etc.

To get an array simply called the `toArray()` method on it, you may also use `flatMap(), mapWithKeys()` etc. Make sure you follow the documentation that is suitable for your version of laravel.